# Twilio Flask Error - Does not respond to SMSs

Tags: python, flask, twilio, ngrok

I had a Twilio application running using Twilio CLI like this:

```
> twilio phone-numbers:update NUMBER --sms-url=http://localhost:5000
```

The above ran successfully.

I then ran this code in a separate terminal:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    # Add a message
    resp.message("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!")

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I used to be able to send and receive the response via SMS after performing these 2 actions, but now I can't. After sending an SMS to it, I get no response. When I open the browser to the ngrok link generated, I get:

[image]

But it does not seem to forward it to my number...

I have also tried it with ngrok without using Twilio-CLI and the same thing happens...

Why is this happening?

**More Info:**

- I am using a Free Trial version and the phone number I am sending a message from is a verified caller ID.
- I pip installed pyngrok and uninstalled it, I am not sure if this had any effect on it, as I realised this problem in the middle of working with it. The problem persists after removing it and rebooting.
- Running the code above, this is the output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "test" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 111-796-191
```

- Refreshing the page gave the following:

```
Failed to complete tunnel connection
The connection to https://5774-121-7-155-247.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:5000.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:5000 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:5000: connect: connection refused
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue where the latest mac os uses the default port for flask. To resolve it, head over to System Preferences > Sharing and unselect the AirPlay Receiver. Or change your default flask port to something other than 5000 using `flask run --port=5002` and restart your ngrok server: `ngrok http 5002`